# How to set jqgrid value dynamically calculated from editform

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqgrid with columns transaction id, debit, credit and balance.
Debit and credits are populated from database and balance is set by calculations from difference of credit - debit.
The editing is done in editform. Once, user changes one of the values of debit or credit, I need the balance column to update in the selected row of the grid.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$myGrid.jqGrid({                
url: myURL + '?method=GetTranactions', 
postData: { 
    prID: function() { return getProv(); },
    mn: function() { return $("#month option:selected").val(); },
    yr: function() { return $("#year option:selected").val(); }
},
datatype: 'json', 
mtype: 'POST',
colNames:['Trx ID','Debit','Credit','Balance',],
colModel :[
    {name:'accttrx_id',index:'accttrx_id', width:75, sorttype:"int", editable:true},
    {name:'debit',index:'debit', 
        width:70, 
        align:"right",
        formatter:'number',
        sorttype:"number",
        editable:true,
        edittype:"text",
        editoptions:{
            size:20,
            defaultValue:'0',                                       
            dataEvents: [   
                {
                    type: 'change',
                    fn: function(e) {
                        var db = $(e.target).val();
                        var cr = $('#credit').val();
                        bal = cr - db;  // got the balance 
                        alert(bal); // how to update balance column for current row?
                        }
                    }
                ]

            },
        editrules:{required:true},
        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
        },
    {name:'balance',index:'balance',
        width:70, 
        align:"right",
        formatter:'number',
        sorttype:"number",
        editable:false},....
```

....................................................................

```
$myGrid.navGrid('#pager', {
search:false,
edit:true,edittitle:"Edit Transation",
add:true,addtitle:"Add Transaction",
refresh:true,
del:true,deltitle:"Delete Transaction"
},
{
beforeShowForm: 
    function(form) { 
        $('#tr_accttrx_id', form).hide();                           
    },
    afterSubmit:
    ..... update balance after submit?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom calculations in the editForm, like you have described here, I usually put the code in the `beforeShowForm` function as you have described here.  Please use something similar to this:

```
beforeShowForm: function() {
    $('#debit,#credit').change(function(){
        $('#balance').val( parseFloat($('#credit').val()) - parseFloat($('#debit').val()) );
    });
},
reloadAfterSubmit: true,
...
```

The jQuery selectors ( `$('#balance')` for example) uses the name of the jqGrid column as the ID selector.  I do this because I know jqGrid makes the column name into the input element ID in the edit form.

**Reload After Submit (show updated info in Grid)**

In order to see your new balance value show up in the grid, use the `reloadAfterSubmit` property of the edit form, which I included in the above example.  Please verify, you are using form Editing or In-Line editing?  If you are using form editing, then the code in my answer should work, if should be used with the `editGridRow` method.  See here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing

**Little Problem with parseFloat and money**

While the above code should work for the most part, please not that the parseFloat command should not be used to do calculations with money.  I have run into rounding issues with this before.  Instead you can use the [BigDeciaml package](https://github.com/iriscouch/bigdecimal.js).

Comment: Thank you Jeffery, on change code works fine as the trigger, I added alert() to check this but, this line below does not set the value in the grid

$('#balance').val( parseFloat($('#credit').val()) - parseFloat($('#debit').val()) );

Comment: You must submit the form to save the data, then reload the grid.

Comment: The values of debit and credit update once I click submit but, the value of balance does not get updated until I refresh the page. 

I added balance to the column in my query as a derived value of the difference of credit and debit columns. That helped me with initial load of the grid but not with updates.

Comment: You can reload the grid after submit, please see my updated answer.

Comment: I added this $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]); and it does not work. Where would you add refresh event?
I tried
afterShowForm: 
 function(form) { 
  $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
},
but, does not work either

Comment: please check out my updated answer:  you have to set the `reloadAfterSubmit` property of the editForm to `true`

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, that exactly what was missing. Once I set reloadAfterSubmit: true it started to work. I did not even need to include $('#debit,#credit').change(function() listener.

Comment: hmmm, dont have enuf reputation, have 13 and need 15